# C# Create Security Event Token

Tags: c#, rest, jwt, .net-4.5

I am working with an API that requires me to create a SET for confirming final delivery of a delivery. There is an example available in Java that goes as follows

```
try {
  JWSSigner signer = new RSASSASigner(signaturePrivateKey.toRSAKey());
  JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
          .issuer(issuer)
          .issueTime(new Date())
          .jwtID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
          .subject(subject)
          .claim("events", Map.of(event, Map.of()))
          .claim("txn", transactionId)
          .build();

  JWSHeader header = JWSHeader.parse(Map.of(
          "typ", "secevent+jwt",
          "kid", signaturePublicKey.getKeyID(),
          "alg", "PS512"
  ));

  SignedJWT signedJWT = new SignedJWT(
          header,
          claimsSet);

  signedJWT.sign(signer);

  String signedAndSerializedSET = signedJWT.serialize(); // => SET, serialized as Base64 encoded string
} catch (JOSEException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not generate SET");
}
```

The "issuer", "subject" and "transactionId" are simply strings. The "event" is a string containing the URL of the endpoint where the SET is to be sent to.

I haven't tried this example for Java since I need it in C# anyways. The package I am trying to use is "jose-jwt". Does someone have an idea how to generate this security event token in C#, with or without that package?

Answer (score 0):

did you try this:

```
{
   "events", new Dictionary<string, object> {
      { "https://...", new { } }
    }

 }
```

You need to add a `Dictionary<string, object>`as an object to the string key.